# Pandas indexes in .value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to find index of some element in series after `.value_counts()`.

For example,

`xls['District'].value_counts()` gives me:

```
район Южное Бутово                 94
район Марьино                      90
район Выхино-Жулебино              86
район Люблино                      80
район Отрадное                     ...
```

How to find index (place) of "район Отрадное", for example(it should be 5)?

Comment: переведите вопрос на русский, чтобы соответствовать правилам русскоязычного SO...

Answer (score 2):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [73]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.choice(['aaa','bbb','ccc'], 100, p=[.6,.25,.15])})

In [74]: df
Out[74]:
    col
0   aaa
1   bbb
2   aaa
3   aaa
4   ccc
5   aaa
6   aaa
..  ...
93  ccc
94  aaa
95  bbb
96  bbb
97  aaa
98  aaa
99  ccc

[100 rows x 1 columns]

In [75]: df['col'].value_counts()
Out[75]:
aaa    53
bbb    27
ccc    20
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

решение:

```
In [76]: res = (df['col'].value_counts().index == 'ccc').argmax()

In [77]: res
Out[77]: 2
```